quarto rendering to html and pdf document with long running computations
I have a qmd file with code running for several hours. I want to render this document in HTML and pdf.
However, if I use
---
format:
  html:
    toc: true
    embed-resources: true
  pdf: default
---

quarto will rerun all the computations twice to create the second output.
Is there a way to run quarto in such a way that it evaluates the code only once but generates both types of outputs?
